# Download image from data base to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem. First I add image from my computer to canvas

```
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) { console.log('fdsf');
    var imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = event.target.result;
    imgObj.onload = function () {
        // start fabricJS stuff
        var newSize = scaleSize(300, 300, imgObj.width, imgObj.height);
        imgObj.width = newSize[0];
        imgObj.height = newSize[1];
        var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
        image.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            angle: 20,
            padding: 10,
            cornersize: 10
        });
        //image.scale(getRandomNum(0.1, 0.25)).setCoords();
        canvas.add(image);

        // end fabricJS stuff
    }

}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

}

Next I save to my data base as String

```
JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON())
```

In data base I see it:

```
{"objects":[{"type":"image","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":300,"height":155,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":20,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","src":"data:image/jpeg;base64,//.../Z","filters":[],"crossOrigin":""}],"background":""}
```

My problem is here. When i want download my Img to canvas. I dont see my img. Why?

I use this method:

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(data["IMG"][i])
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=canvas.toSVG();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

`json` here is a variable that has the string json:

```
json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());
```

It should work. I made you a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2zLk8tn/). The `canvas.clear()` is there just to clear to see that Load Json works.